# How can i send message in Amazon SQS faster?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I am using the AWS SDK for Java V2 to send a message to Amazon SQS. From my EC2 server it will take 97ms to 108ms to send a message. Is there any way to reduce the time taken to send? What is the average ideal time required to send a message? Is there any feature like a connection pool in aws-sdk to reduce this connection creation time?

Comment: Can I ask your particular use-case? Are you needing to send LOTS of data in a short time period? What type of data are you sending? Your use-case might be a better fit for MQTT with AWS IoT, which is a lighter protocol and is commonly used for sending sensor data.

Comment: You can send up to 10 msg in on request, using `batch` operation. This effectively reduces a sending time per message.